# Need regex to match the given string

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to match a particular string, say `1.4.5` in the below string . My string will be like

```
absdfsdfsdfc1.4.5kdecsdfsdff
```

I have a regex which is giving `[c1.4.5k]` as an output. But I want to match only `1.4.5`. I have tried this pattern:

```
[^\\W](\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d)[^\\d]
```

But no luck. I am using Java.
Please let me know the pattern.

Comment: Nathan,this is matching everything. I want to match only 1.4.5.

Comment: It will match the whole thing, but the part you want will be in the first group which is `match.group(1)`.

Comment: Nathan, But there can be many numbers which will match the same pattern. I cannot use match.group(1) since i will be putting all the results into a list for further processing. Consider "absdfsdfsdfc**1.4.5**kdec456456.567sdfsdff22.33.55ffkidhfuh122.33.44" as my string and i need to match 1.4.5

Answer (score 1):

When I read your expression `[^\\W](\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d)[^\\d]` correctly, then you want a word character before and not a digit ahead. Is that correct?

For that you can use [lookbehind and lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Those assertions do only check their condition, but they do not match, therefore that stuff is not included in the result.

```
(?<=\\w)(\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d)(?!\\d)
```

Because of that, you can remove the capturing group. You are also repeating yourself in the pattern, you can simplify that, too:

```
(?<=\\w)\\d(?:\\.\\d){2}(?!\\d)
```

Would be my pattern for that. (The `?:` is a non capturing group)

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should do it : `([0-9]+\\.?)+`

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expression

```
((?<!\d)\d(?:\.\d(?!\d))+)
```

As a Java string:

```
"((?<!\\d)\\d(?:\\.\\d(?!\\d))+)"
```

Comment: Koen thanks for the answer. What if i have a String like "absdfsdfsdfc**1.4.5**kdec456456.567sdfsdff22.33.55ffkidhfuh122.33.44" In this String i want to match only 1.4.5. Strictly single digit separted by a (.) symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are vague. Do you need to match a series of exactly 3 numbers with exactly two dots?

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+
```

Which could be written as

```
([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+
```

Do you need to match x many cases of a number, seperated by x-1 dots in between?

```
([0-9]+\.)+[0-9]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use look ahead and look behind.

```
(?<=c)[\d\.]+(?=k)
```

Where c is the character that would be immediately before the 1.4.5 and k is the character immediately after 1.4.5. You can replace c and k with any regular expression that would suit your purposes

Answer (score 0):

```
String str= "absdfsdfsdfc**1.4.5**kdec456456.567sdfsdff22.33.55ffkidhfuh122.33.44"; 
String regex ="[0-9]{1}\\.[0-9]{1}\\.[0-9]{1}";  
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);                    
if (matcher.find())
{
String year = matcher.group(0);

System.out.println(year);
}
else
{
    System.out.println("no match found");
}
```